# PHP Mysqli Fetch from table where

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently working on a user system on my website, I've a table setup `users` for users to register, I want to retrieve information from the table for specific users.

`users` is a table with 5 columns username, password, email, level, gold

I have a $_SESSION['username'] which is equal to the logged in username and I want to get their level and gold from `users` and set them as $userLevel and $userGold. How can I do this?

EDIT

The following code gets all the users info I just want a specific users info

```
$sql="SELECT username, level, gold FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Username: " . $row["username"]. " - Level: " . $row["level"]. " - Gold: " . $row["gold"]. "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: There are many tutorials for this, or are you having issues with some actual code and/or a specific issue? Sounds like you are asking how to run a `select` query currently.

Comment: I've gone through many tutorials but none have exactly what I want to know

Comment: Yea, you will have to modify the code a bit but have you done that and are having a specific issue?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how to do this I don't have a specific issue

Comment: This is too broad for SO as is.

Comment: Maybe provide some of your code, it'll be easier to get an answer that you want

Comment: @chris85 Could you give me any advice or point me in the right direction?

Comment: `SELECT username, level, gold FROM users where username = ?`. Then bind `$_SESSION['username']`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: *Simple,* use a `WHERE` clause from the session array. It's *MySQL 101*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to prevent MySQL Injection:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['username']);
```

Code to select the row, WHERE username will be equal to the user logged in

```
$sql = "SELECT username, level, gold FROM users WHERE `username` = '$username';
```

To echo, you can use your existing code

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Username: " . $row["username"] . " - Level: " . $row["level"] . " - Gold: " . $row["gold"]. "<br>";
    }
```

UPDATED to reflect MySQLi, instead of MySQL and the MySQL code to make it clearer.
Thanks @Fred-ii- for point out.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` that doesn't mix in with mysqli_. and `WHERE username = " . $username;` will fail if that's a string.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Updated answer, thanks for pointing out

Comment: the OP is attempting to modify your answer http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11182344 using `mysql_`. *Huh?* Plus, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires a connection as its first parameter. No idea why the OP wants to do that, it's sabotage if anything. `$result = $conn->query($sql);` is mysqli_ syntax, not mysql_.

Comment: I forgot to say; you're welcome ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("select level, gold from users where username={pass_username_variable_here}"));
```

To echo level:

```
echo $data['level'];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql="SELECT username, level, gold FROM users Where username ==".$_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: why would you want them to use LIKE? plus that will fail; it's a string *more than likely*.

Comment: A single `=` is used for comparison in SQL. This also is still open to SQL injections. You also should always write in your answer what you did and why.